# Solana equivalent to www.usecocreate.io for Web3 loyalty program?

Tags: nft, metadata, api, rewards, walletprovider

I am volunteering for a major presidential campaign.

The campaign is considering using NFTs as rewards to incentivize donations and engagement. I am exploring platforms that offer community management, token management, campaign building and rewards redemption. The UX must be designed for normies - no wallet, no crypto, no problem.

I found a few options in other ecosystems. I'm partial to Solana. Are there projects developing in the community ready for a use case like this?